# Multiline Regex Lookbehind Failing in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I'm trying to parse a particular text file. One portion of the file is:

```
Installed     HotFix
n/a           Internet Explorer - 0
Applications:
```

In powershell, this is currently in a file C:\temp\software.txt. I'm trying to get it to return all lines in between "HotFix" and "Applications:" (As there may be more in the future.)

My current command looks like this:

```bsh
Get-Content -Raw -Path 'C:\temp\software.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '(?<=HotFix\n)((.*?\n)+)(?=Applications)' }
```

Other regex I've tried:

```bsh
'(?<=HotFix`n)((.*?`n)+)(?=Applications)'
'(?<=HotFix`n)((.*?\n)+)(?=Applications)'
'(?<=HotFix\n)((.*?`n)+)(?=Applications)'
'(?<=HotFix$)((.*?\n)+)(?=Applications)'
'(?<=HotFix)((.*?\n)+)(?=Applications)'
'(?<=HotFix)((.*?`n)+)(?=Applications)'
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to look for the lines starting with `Installed` and `Applications:` and taking all the lines in between?

Comment: What exactly was the problem with all the regexes you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Select-String` will provide better results here:

```
((Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\software.txt' textfile -Raw |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?sm)(?<=HotFix\s*$).*?(?=^Applications:)' -AllMatches).Matches.Value).Trim()
```

Regex modifier `s` is used because you are expecting the `.` character to potentially match newline characters. Regex modifier `m` is used so that end of string `$` and start of string `^` characters can be matched on each line. Together that syntax is `(?sm)` in PowerShell.

`Where {$_ -match ...}` will return anything that makes the condition true. Since you are passing a `Get-Content -Raw` output, the entire contents of the file will be one string and therefore the entire string will output on a `true` condition.

Since you used `-match` here against a single string, any successful matches will be stored in the `$matches` automatic variable. Your matched string would be available in `$matches[0]`. If you were expecting multiple matches, `-match` will not work as constructed here.

---

Alternatively, the .NET `Matches()` method of the Regex class, can also do the job:

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Content 'c:\temp\software.txt' -Raw),'(?sm)(?<=HotFix\s*$).*?(?=^Applications:)').Value.Trim()
```

Without `Trim()`, you'd need to understand your newline character situation:

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Content software.txt -Raw),'(?m)(?<=HotFix\r?\n?)[^\r\n]+(?=\r?\n?^Applications:)').Value
```

---

A non-regex, alternative could use a `switch` statement.

```
switch -File Software.txt -Regex {
    'HotFix\s*$' { $Hotfix,$Applications = $true,$false }
    '^Applications:' { $Applications = $true }
    default {
        if ($Hotfix -and !$Applications) {
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file into a string the following regular expression will read the lines of interest:

```
/(?<=HotFix\n).*?(?=\nApplications:)/s
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/NELAFM/3/)

The regex reads:

> Match zero or more characters, lazily (`?`), preceded by the string `"HotFix\n"` and followed by the string `"\nApplications:"`.

`(?<=HotFix\n)` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?=\nApplications:)` is a *positive lookahead*.

The flag `s` (`/s`) causes `.*?` to continue past the ends of lines. (Some languages have a different flag that has the same effect.)

`.*?` (lazy match) is used in place of `.*` (greedy match) in the event that there is more than one line following the `"Hot Fix"` line that begins `"Applications:"`. The lazy version will match the first; the greedy version, the last.

I would not be inclined to use a regex for this task. For one, the entire file must be read into a string, which could be problematic (memory-wise) if the file is sufficiently large. Instead, I would simply read the file line-by-line, keeping only the current line in memory. Once the "Bad Fix" line has been read, save the following lines until the "Applications:" line is read. Then, after closing the file, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lookarounds, you could make use of a capturing group

First match the line that ends with `HotFix`. Then capture in group 1 all the following lines that do not start with Applications and then match `Applications`

```
^.*\bHotFix\r?\n((?:(?!Applications:).*\r?\n)+)Applications:
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*\bHotFix\r?\n` Match the line that ends with HotFix
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!Applications:).*\r?\n` Match the whole line if it does not start with `Applications:`
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times to match all lines
- `)` Close group 1
- `Applications:` Match literally

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%5cbHotFix%5cr%3f%5cn%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!Applications%3a%29.*%5cr%3f%5cn%29%2b%29Applications%3a&i=Installed+++++HotFix%0d%0an%2fa+++++++++++Internet+Explorer+-+0%0d%0aApplications%3a)

[image]